# Remove characters from # to end in all cells of a column (vba-EXCEL)

Tags: vba, excel

In an Excel i have these fields:

```
OOK: vpjsghe.fkds 2002 field1 Field2 # v2.0.11-28
OOK: vpjsghe.fkds 2002 field3 Field4 # v2.0.11-289
OOK: vpjsghe.fkds 2002 field5 Field6 # v2.0.11-101
OOK: vpjsghe.fkds 2002 field7 Field8 # v2.0.11-2892
```

and i need to remove the text from # until the end of the string to have this:

```
OOK: vpjsghe.fkds 2002 field1 Field2
OOK: vpjsghe.fkds 2002 field3 Field4
OOK: vpjsghe.fkds 2002 field5 Field6
OOK: vpjsghe.fkds 2002 field7 Field8
```

the # only appear once in each field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a formula

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("#",A1)-1)
```

Where A1 is eg. `OOK: vpjsghe.fkds 2002 field1 Field2 # v2.0.11-28`

But be aware that this results in a trailing space. To remove that you can either use `TRIM()` or find with a space `FIND(" #",A1)`.

Answer (score 1):

for VBA code you can use something like

```
    left(sheets(1).range("A1").value,(instr(0,sheets(1).range("A1").value,"#",vbBinarycompare))-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in function in the ribbon (Data -> text to columns) that will allow you to use # as a delimter and split it, then just delete the column you don't want. It's easier than the LEFT formula and you don't have to search for the character.